# Java object is null when even if it is not null in similar function

Tags: java

I am trying to create a class for Trie and testing it but when I call insert method crawl is null, please let me know why is that.
Search function is working fine but don't know why only insert function is behaving like this.
I am surprised with the output, maybe shows my naivete in java.
Please help with this.

```
public class Trie {
    private Trie[] children;
    private boolean isEndOfWorld;
    
    public Trie() {
        children = new Trie[26];
        isEndOfWorld = false;
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++) {
            children[i] = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean search(String str) {
        Trie crawl = this;
        int len = str.length();
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
            int index = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if(crawl.children[index] == null) {
                break;
            }
            crawl = crawl.children[index];
        }
        
        return crawl.isEndOfWorld && i==len;
    }
    public void insert(String str) {
        Trie crawl = this;
        int len = str.length();
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
            int index = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if(crawl == null) {
                System.out.println("Object is null");
                break;
            }
            if(crawl.children[index] == null) {
                crawl.children[i] = new Trie();
            }
            crawl = crawl.children[index];
        }
        crawl.isEndOfWorld = true;
    }
    
}

public class TestTrie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trie ob = new Trie();
        System.out.println(ob.search("check"));
        ob.insert("check");
    }

}

output-
false
Object is null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Trie.insert(Trie.java:42)
    at TestTrie.main(TestTrie.java:10)

Why Object is null?
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `insert`?

Comment: You change the crawl reference to point to some child node. If that reference happens to be null, you break out of the loop but then try to do `crawl.isEndOfWorld = true`

Comment: Why would you expect any of the elements of `crawl.children` **not ** to be null on a newly constructed `Trie` object?

Comment: I think your line `crawl.children[i] = new Trie();` should be `crawl.children[index] = new Trie();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in line:

```
crawl.children[i] = new Trie();
```

it should be:

```
crawl.children[index] = new Trie();
```

because `i` represents the place (index) of the current character in `str` while the variable `index` represents its place in the alphabet (in `children`).

Answer (score 0):

If you trace the loop in `insert(String)`, you will find that at the second iteration, the `index` value is `7` in which no object has been instantiated.